# Problem installing Debian wheezy from USB stick

Tags: debian, usb, system-installation

I try to install Debian wheezy on my IBM ThinkPad X40 2372-CTO via USB stick. First i do `zcat boot.img.gz > /dev/sdb` with this [image](ftp://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/hd-media/). After that i do `cp debian-*-netinst.iso /mnt/sdb` with this [image](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/daily-builds/daily/arch-latest/i386/iso-cd/).

When I try to install debian from the USB stick the following happens. First I get `SYSLINUX .... aborted. boot:`. When I press enter I see the Installer menu. When I choose `Install` the machine reboots. What am I doing wrong here? Are these the wrong images? How can I debug this?

Comment: Random comments: does your computer support booting from a USB stick, and is the partition in question a FAT partition? Also, why sdb? What else do you have on that stick?

Comment: hi, yes it supports it. done it already with debian 5. `sdb` because `sda` is the internal hd on the machine where i do the copying. the stick is completely used for this installation.

Comment: Testing images are sometimes broken, try an [earlier build](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/daily-builds/daily/). You can also [directly copy the iso onto the stick](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid), what happens if you do this?

Comment: Are you using http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch04s03.html.en as documentation?

Comment: @Gilles I tried to copy it directly. reboots again. I think I'll another image now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved: memory was broken.